# Error when adding polygon overlay to MKMapView

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I have a map view that is conforming to UIViewRepresentable to use it in my SwiftUI app. When my view model updates with data after a successful API call, I add to my array of overlays with an array of coordinates to represent a map boundary. This array of overlays is then passed to the view and then the overlay is added as an MKPolygon in updateUIView. I return a render this polygon in the delegate method.

```
struct MapViewUIKit: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var annotations: [MKPointAnnotation]
    @Binding var mapRect: MKMapRect
    @Binding var overlays: [MKOverlay]
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        view.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, animated: true)
        
        if annotations.count != view.annotations.count {
            view.removeAnnotations(view.annotations)
            view.addAnnotations(annotations)
        }
        
        if overlays.count != view.overlays.count {
            view.removeOverlays(view.overlays)
            view.addOverlays(overlays)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapViewUIKit
        
        init(_ parent: MapViewUIKit) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            parent.mapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            if overlay is MKPolygon {
                let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
                renderer.strokeColor = .magenta
                renderer.fillColor = .blue
                return renderer
            }
            return MKOverlayRenderer()
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I zoom into the area where the polygon should be rendered, I get the following error and there is no overlay

```
Wrapped around the polygon without finishing... :-(
List has 6 nodes:
    1 2 4 5 6 0 
2022-03-14 15:01:36.159966-0400 Synop[3702:59086] [VKDefault] Building failed to triangulate!
```

I've tried searching what this error means to no avail. I know my overlay is being added and with the proper coordinates as well with print statements in the relevant places.

Comment: Have you tried passing your `overlays` array as `[MKPolygon]`? I receive exactly the same error message myself but it doesn't interfere with the execution of my code. I think it might be some bug in the Xcode beta that I'm hoping will disappear in a future release.

Comment: Hi I have not tried that. I will do that and report back later tonight. This error pops up once the visible rectangle of my map is where the overlay should be. I should have also made it clear in my post that my overlay is not showing up in my map along with this error